# Specify crs of raster file by Python/Rasterio?

Tags: python, raster, coordinate-system, rasterio

I use the Rasterio to cut out roofs of buildings, roofs are polygons. I would like to set up crs of felled roofs. Is it possible to do that by Rasterio?

I can set up crs of layer, layer.crs = 'epsg:2180', but how can I do that for raster file?

My code to cutting out roofs of buildings:

```
def cutting_out(df, start, end):
    for index, row in df.iloc[start:end].iterrows():
        if len(row['1_5000_pi025']) == 1:
        #1url
            coo = shapely.wkt.loads(row['geometry'])
            multiplier = int(row['liczba_kon'])
            coo_buffer = coo.buffer(3 * multiplier)
            lokalnyid = row['lokalnyid']
            tiff = str(row['1_5000_pi025'][0])
            with rasterio.open(f'/mnt/qnap/geo_tiff_1_5000_p025/{tiff}') as src:
                out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, [coo_buffer], crop=True)
                out_meta = src.meta
                out_meta.update(
                    {
                        "driver": "GTiff",
                        "height": out_image.shape[1],
                        "width": out_image.shape[2],
                        "transform": out_transform,
                    }
                )
                with rasterio.open(f'/mnt/qnap/geo_tiff_roofs_testy3/{lokalnyid}'+'_025'+'.tif', "w", **out_meta) as dest:
                    dest.write(out_image)
```

Comment: If `src.crs` is not `None` it will automatically get written to `dest.crs`, if `src.crs` is `None` and you know it is  `epsg:2180`, just add `"crs": "epsg:2180"` to `out_meta.update`

Answer (score 2):

As user2856 commented, when opening a new file for writing you can just add "crs" argument in "rasterio.open":

```
with rasterio.open(f'/.../{lokalnyid}'+'_025'+'.tif', "w", crs='EPSG:2180', **out_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(out_image)
```

An example from rasterio documentation:

```
profile = {'driver': 'GTiff', 'height': 100, 'width': 100, 'count': 1, 'dtype': rasterio.uint8}
with rasterio.open('/tmp/foo.tif', 'w', crs='EPSG:3857', **profile) as dst:
...     pass # write data to this Web Mercator projection dataset.
```

Source: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/georeferencing.html?highlight=CRS#coordinate-reference-system